# Javascripts codes that will memorize user previous setting on Radio flash Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I am using a script for flash player that is for streaming radio live in my blog. It is working well but there is only one missing. If the user select the radio to play (from OFF to Play Mode) or if the user adjust volume to his/her selection, it won't keep those selected setting when the user goes to another pages. I want to keep their last selected settings like the way cookie works.

For example, please see this blog >>> http://pyinnyartree.blogspot.com/

the scripts is as following >>>

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hosted.musesradioplayer.com/mrp.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({ 
'url':'http://192.184.9.79:8316/;', 'codec':'mp3', 'volume':10, 'autoplay':true,
'jsevents':true, 'buffering':5, 'title':'Live Radio', 'welcome':'Welcome',  
'bgcolor':'#FFFFFF', 'skin':'radiovoz', 'width':180, 'height':30 });
</script>
```

Please help. I need codes. I want to provide the readers to keep their last selected settings after changes.

Remarks: I found FAQ website from Muses help, they said if jsevent is enable, a developer could write java script to keep those last selected setting or even more. Please see this >> http://www.musesradioplayer.com/faq#faq16

thanks in advance.
oak soe oo

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to look at how this particular player works, but assuming that you are able to

1) keep track of the state (perhaps by creating an event in JavaScript that gets run when it changes)

and

2) set the state via JavaScript on startup

then you should have the event save settings to localstorage and read those values upon page load.  (If your site had user accounts and you wanted to be able to save settings across computers/browsers, then you would want to use an AJAX call instead of localstorage.)

Comment: My case would be more similar with #1 where you stated above. There is no user account. 
For your convenience, I've just made another blog where you can study the case more closely. Please see " http://pyinnyartree.blogspot.com/ ". There are two labels as "News" and "Sport". You will see how it is working when you change between two labels or when you call a particular news to read more. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a case for cookies. You already know that, it seems.

General scheme is as follows:

1. Replace parameters you want to save with appropriate variables you're going to declare on step 3.
2. Implement `function musesCallback(event,value)`, which, if called with some specific arguments, would write selected URL and maybe some other settings into cookies. (it will be called by the player, not you, that's the mechanism of *callbacks*)
3. Include a JS snippet above the player (`<head> </head>`?) to check whether the user's browser has certain cookies. If so - it should assign the values from there to some of your variables put into configuration. If not - it should assign some default values, which you replaced with variables on step 1.

That is, if a user visits your site, the script checks cookies, finds nothing and assigns default values - that is, the effect is the same as from the code you have above.

But if a script finds cookies it has left before, then it replaces values in configuration variables with values from cookies before player even starts, so that it starts with values remembered before.

During playback, player will occasionally call `musesCallback` to notify of some events - some of them seem to be configuration changes, and should write new settings to user's cookies.

Comment: Thank you for your point of instruction. I am a new to java world. So that I can't be able to write that script on my own. :( . Can you please help me have the code?

Comment: @oaksoeoo, I'm not that much of a JavaScript man as well, but knowledge of any somewhat similar language should help. And Java is not JavaScript, by the way.